# mongo db : get sub array from an array of objects with values within a range in a single document

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, pymongo, nosql-aggregation

#### What I have:

- A `mongodb` collection, say `collection1`
- `collection1` contains two columns viz. `id` and `data`
- `id` is `int` but the twist is `data` is an array of objects and *its keys are string but numeric*
- `collection1` contains ***only one document*** *(for the sake of this question)*

**collection1**

```json
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "k1" : "001",
            "k2" : "v1"
        }, 
        {
            "k1" : "002",
            "k2" : "v2"
        }, 
        {
            "k1" : "004",
            "k2" : "v3"
        }, 
        {
            "k1" : "010",
            "k2" : "v4"
        }, 
        {
            "k1" : "015",
            "k2" : "v5"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### What I want to have:

I want to fetch all objects from the `data` array which have `k1` from `003` to `012` both included, from the document with `_id = 1`

#### What I'm getting on searching on internet:

I got to know about aggregate function in `mongo` and `$match, $project, $filter`, etc. I'm new to `mongo` and unable to get the intuition behind aggregation.

I know I can achieve this through custom functions, but it would contain a for loop which will impact the performance. There must a better way to achieve it but I'm not able to figure it out.

> Note: I also want to achieve the same with `pymongo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I am not aware of `pymongo` but below query is the basic idea (as long as you put all MongoDB operators inside double quotes `""` directly using this query must work):

Try this:

```js
db.collection1.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "_id": 1 }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "data": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$data",
                    "as": "item",
                    "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$gte": [{ "$toInt": "$$item.k1" }, 3] },
                            { "$lte": [{ "$toInt": "$$item.k1" }, 12] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "data" : [
        {
            "k1" : "004",
            "k2" : "v3"
        },
        {
            "k1" : "010",
            "k2" : "v4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: that is perfect , loads of thanks, can you provide few resources(s) of the `aggregate framework` which have some good examples?

Comment: Check this: https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M121/about. I learnt basics from here: https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M001/about I recommend learn basics before aggregation.